# Making tmux let vim resize putty window

Tags: vim, putty, tmux

When using vim in a putty window, a resize command such as `:set columns=161` will change the width of the putty window to match the new size. When running under tmux, putty doesn't get the command to resize.

Is there a way to tell tmux to let vim resize the putty window?